# How to validate coupon code is valid for old customer in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2

How to validate coupon code is valid for old customer in magento 2.4. I used observer but unable to do

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question and add the code in question?

Comment: Didn't understand your question please explain more

Comment: I want only old customer (who already purchase from us) can only apply particular coupon code in magento 2.4